# recurrence relation, limits

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $a_1\in(0,1)$ and $a_{n+1}=a_n(1-a_n^2)$ for $n\ge 1$.

Prove that $\lim \sqrt{n}a_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and find $\lim \left(\sqrt{n}a_n - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\frac{n}{\ln n}$.

For the first part, I used identity $na_n^2=\frac{n}{\frac{1}{a_n^2}}$ and Stolz-Cesaro theorem.

How to deal with the more advanced one? I don't see the use of Stolz-Cesaro here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the first step, one easily sees that $a_n^2\le\frac13$ for $n\ge 2$. The sequence is monotonically decreasing. Select some $N$ and set $ε=a_n^2$

Consider $b_n=a_n^{-2}$. Then
$$
b_{n+1}=b_n(1-a_n^2)^{-2}=b_n(1+2a_n^2+3a_n^4+4a_n^6+…+ka_n^{2k-2}+…)
\\
=b_n+2+3a_n^2+4a_n^4+…
$$
So we get at first 
$$
b_n+2\le b_{n+1} \le b_n+2+8ε
$$
for $n$ larger a suitable $N$. Thus
$$
b_N+2k\le b_{N+k}\le b_N+2(1+4ε)k
\\ \iff \\ 
C+2n\le b_n\le C+2(1+4ε)n
\\ \iff \\ 
\frac{1}{C+2(1+4ε)n}\le a_n^2\le\frac{1}{C+2n}
$$

---

In asymptotic terms that means $a_n^2=\frac1{2n}+o(\frac1n)$. Inserting that in the formula for $b_n$ gives the improved estimate
$$
b_n=C+2n+\frac32\ln(n)+o(1)
$$
which leads to
$$
\sqrt{2n}a_n=1-\frac38\frac{\ln(n)}{n}+o\bigl(\frac1n\bigr)
$$